# Is state user specifc?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

im new to Node and React. Now i am playing with react and redux. It is awesome! But at least there is one question. Is the redux store user specifc or get every user the same obejct with the same values?

Edit:

In my scenario different User work with the App on the same time. Do they always have the same state. Is the state syncron between different users.

Or get every user an specifc state in redux.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Without your code or a detailed explanation of it, we can't see what do you mean by `users` and how yoou manage your redux store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React runs in the client-side as JavaScript, so by default each tab where your application is running has got its own state that has no guarantee to be the same.

To synchronize your state between your tabs of the same browsers, cookies can be used. To synchronize your state between your different users, they have to communicate with each others so some implementation has to be done on the client side, for example with sessions or websockets.

But keep in mind that **there is no easy `sync` switch**! State synchronization requires a lot of implementation and even if there might be some libraries that help with that, synchronizing the state between several instances of a React app requires possibly a lot of skills and code.

It's hard to go further in answering with the little amount of explanation you gave without speculating, but you got the gist.

Comment: Thanks! That is a good Information! I will dig deeper in the research!

Comment: you can also make use of the browsers localStorage to store some user information, such as jwt tokens so that they don't need to log in each time they initialise the application, though this should be used wisely (I only use it for just the tokens)

Comment: Great! Also, it might be weird to new users, but in Stack Overflow, [thank-you comments should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - if you're happy with an answer, upvote or accept it ;)

Comment: @ThatCoderGuy beware! localStorage is super cool. But please [avoid using it for security-related data](https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04)!

Answer (score 1):

Because React is served from the client (browser), the state of a react app belongs to the instance of the application itself.

So if you have 2 tabs open, each tab has its own instance of the application and therefore have their own state.

No matter if you are logged in as the same user within the app or different users, it's the application which has its state (unlike a session, which you would usually find on a backend)

The same applies to redux, the state belongs to the instance of the application.

I hope this provides some clarity

Comment: Thank you very much. I know, it is not an expert question. Im struggeling a little bit with the differences between what happend on Server-side and what happend on the Client-Side. But your answer give me some clearance!

Comment: You're welcome, it is quite a paradigm shift, but it's good to ask these kind of questions

Comment: Im Just expirienced in backend. So this is New to ne :)